# Creating a class while using cascading and PLP

Tags: c++, class

So I am trying to create a class ( Version ) with data members. The member functions are setters ( allow for cascading calls ) and getters ( use PLP and handle constant objects ). In the int main, it allows the user to input the numbers, then it needs to use cascading member functions calls for all data members in one statement and display the version by calling the getters and have them return just the value of the data member.

I pretty much coded everything, but I feel like I'm missing a step or doing something wrong with the parameters. My error says that I need a ')' for my setters, but I feel like it is a different problem. I did not get all my notes for how to do this, so can someone tell me what I am missing or need to fix? Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Version
{
private:
    int major, minor, service_pack;
public:
    Version();
    Version& setMajor(int maj);
    Version& setMinor(int min);
    Version& setService_pack(int sp);
    int getMinor(Version *const this);
    int getMajor(Version* const this);
    int getService_pack(Version* const this);
};

Version::Version()
{
    major = 0;
    minor = 0;
    service_pack = 0;
}

Version& Version::setMinor(int min)
{
    minor = min;
    return *this;
}

Version& Version::setMinor(int maj)
{
    major = maj;
    return *this;
}

Version& Version::setMinor(int sp)
{
    service_pack = sp;
    return *this;
}

int Version::getMinor(Version* const this)
{
    return this->minor;
    (*this).minor;
}

int Version::getMajor(Version* const this)
{
    return this->major;
    (*this).major;
}

int Version::getService_pack(Version* const this)
{
    return this->service_pack;
    (*this).service_pack;
}

int main()
{
    int minor, major, service_pack;
    Version a;
    cout << "Enter minor, major, and service pack: " << endl;
    cin >> minor, major, service_pack;

    a.setMinor(minor).setMajor(major).setService_pack(service_pack);

    cout << "Major: " << a.getMajor() << "Minor: "<< a.getMinor << "Service Pack: " << a.getService_pack();

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenbtheses in `main()` for diplaying `a.getMinor()`.  Without the parentheses, you'd refer to the member function itself.

Your getters should in principle take no arguments if you return the value. In any case, avoid passing arguments called `this`.

One further improvement you could make, would be to declare the getters as `const`:

```
int Version::getMinor() const
{
    return minor;   // this-> is only needed to disambiguate
}
```

Comment: Oh good eye! but do you know if my parameters for my getters are right?

Comment: No, your getters should take no argument.